# Is it possible to place a banner stating that programming questions are off-topic here?

Tags: feature-request

We seem to have a lot of questions about programming showing up now, which are off-topic (and not enough people VTCing!).

Examples: [(1)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2457/145) [(2)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2462/145) [(3)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2451/145)

Is it possible to place a banner at the top of the page, stating that these questions are off-topic, such as the one on [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com)? Or is that only available for graduated sites?

Comment: Mithical, do you have any screenshot of what it looked like on Mi Yodeya? It doesn't seem like such a banner exists now?

Comment: @user1271772 - I was *probably* referring to https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX6q6.png at the time

Comment: @Mithrandir I see.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I agree that this is a concerning trend. Though we [have an on-topic page](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1252/75) that categorizes such questions as off-topic, there is not a direct link to that help center article on the asking form. [Relevant MSE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213935/295684)

Though we put together an on-topic page, the [tour page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour) was neglected. People are encouraged to take the tour when they first sign up; for some, it might be the only topicality-related document they read. Just now, I changed the "ask" and "don't ask" bulleted lists away from the default generic stuff to something that summarizes our help center guidelines. **Suggestions for improvements are welcome!** Hopefully this change will help our problem; if it doesn't, we can consider more conspicuous help text.

In regard to the examples you brought up (thank you for bringing specifics!):

1. This question was voluntarily removed by its author after receiving some comments about topicality.
2. This seems interesting to me; I think one could argue that it's asking about ways of thinking as opposed to asking for some code.
3. This is indeed a question about programming. It is [in the Close Votes queue](https://ai.stackexchange.com/review/close/1135) at the moment pending review. As you said, it would be very good to have more people reviewing. There are currently 16 non-moderator users with [the close/reopen vote privilege](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions); I encourage all such users to [have a look at that queue](https://ai.stackexchange.com/review/close/).

Comment: Is seeing how many users have a privilege a moderator-only power?

Comment: @Mithrandir I just counted the number of users [on the reputation-ordered user page](http://ai.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) with more than 500 reputation. I'm not aware of a feature that shows the users with a given privilege. If the number got too big to count by hand, a Data Explorer query could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering what kind of tools you guys have :P

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing concerning about it.  It's just the community speaking in regards to what they want to talk about.  Let's quit trying to fight a rising tide and accept that AI is an inherently technical topic, and enthusiasts are going to want to ask technical questions.