# What is in scope under the "implementation of machine learning" exclusion?

Tags: discussion

Some implementation questions like [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/reproduce-firefly-algorithm-experiments-of-original-paper) and [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/how-to-fill-in-missing-transitions-when-sampling-an-mdp-transition-table) are not about Machine Learning. They are getting closed anyway, as the actual topic would rather be on another SE site.

I wonder if the "not about... the implementation of machine learning" on the [help center page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is misleading a few people. That phrasing originates in a [discussion](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1252/169) about acceptable topics, and the term "implementation" still seems problematic.

How about "algorithmic or implementation details, software library or specific hardware-related" kind of phrasing? The idea is to exclude more implementation-related questions, but only the ones that pertain to step-by-step guidance through an implementation or library.

In short, a couple examples under the latter proposal:

- NG: How to implement A* with TensorFlow?
- OK: How to implement Case-Based Reasoning with Neural Networks?

Note the intended use of the "implementation" word in both questions. If there is something here, I still think there is a need for better examples (the OK is too broad yet).

---

Disclaimer: I am a proponent of having *some* implementation questions here.

Comment: Isn't "How to implement Case-Based Reasoning with Neural Networks?" an algorithmic  question?

Comment: It can go as far as an algorithm, yes. It could be as "simple" as explaining how CBR can be modeled with NN. I do not like my own example. I am trying to make a point that implementation is not necessarily about ML, and we should reflect that in the help center.

Comment: As a side note, questions about machine learning implementations are often not getting closed [Technical questions are not getting closed](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/q/1279/4)